# Expand Pandas columns with lists

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a dataframe with one row that looks like the following:

```
a   b   c   d   e
1   [2,4]   [2,7]   apple   orange
```

I know i how to do this with one list column, but wasn't sure how this changes with multiple list columns.  I essentially want to expand the dataframe into n rows depending how many elements in each list.  The number is always the equivalent between the columns with lists.  So the example above would become:

```
a   b   c   d   e
1   2   2   apple   orange
1   4   7   apple   orange
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Funny how a simple problem can be difficult:

```
(pd.DataFrame(df.loc[0,['b','c']].to_list(), columns=['b','c'])
   .join(df.loc[df.index.repeat(len(df.loc[0,'b'])),['a','d','e']].reset_index(drop=True))
)
```

Comment: It's funny how that works out.  I was thinking about doing something similar to this, but I figured there'd be a pandas method similar to 'explode' that I didn't know about.  Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way using `explode` to arrive at the solution:

```
ndf = pd.concat([df.explode('c').drop('b', axis=1), df.explode('b').drop('c', axis=1)], axis=1)

ndf.loc[:,~ndf.columns.duplicated()]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not shure if this solution will work for your real `dataframe`. It seems to me, that this only works because of the simple example data.

```py
import pandas as pd
import io

t = '''
a   b   c   d   e
1   [2,4,5]   [2,7,2]   apple   orange'''

# Setting up the dataframe with lists in `b` and `c`.
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep='\s+', converters={'b': eval, 'c': eval})

df.apply(pd.Series.explode)
```

Out:

```
   a  b  c      d       e
0  1  2  2  apple  orange
0  1  4  7  apple  orange
0  1  5  2  apple  orange
```

Answer (score 0):

if your lists are all the same length you can use the pandas dataframe constructor with a dictionary:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.Series([1, [2,4], [2,7], 'apple', 'orange'],
                  index=['a','b','c','d','e'])
data = pd.DataFrame(data).T
print(data, '\n\n')

output = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(data.columns, data.loc[0])))
print(output)
```

```
   a       b       c      d       e
0  1  [2, 4]  [2, 7]  apple  orange


   a  b  c      d       e
0  1  2  2  apple  orange
1  1  4  7  apple  orange
```